# Is there a way to conditionally validate with class-validator?

Tags: validation, conditional-statements, nestjs, option-type, class-validator

I'm building a CRUD for users using Nest.js
I'd like to have the POST and PATCH receive the same DTO but have some fields optional in PATCH but mandatory in POST.
I couldn't find a way to do this other than keep all properties @IsOptional and manually write the validation in the code for POST requests.

Is there a better way to do it with class-validator ?

Comment: Why don't you use two separate models for POST and PATCH with specific validation rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NestJS Provides a beautiful solution for your problem,

you can use `PartialType`, *To create a type with the same fields, but with each one optional, use PartialType() passing the class reference (PsotDto) as an argument:*

```
export class PatchDto extends PartialType(PostDto) {}
```

Comment: Thanks, I also found a way to do it using "@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ skipMissingProperties: true }))" on the method level (and remove the globalPipes), but your suggestion seems to be designated exactly for my problem

Answer (score 2):

You can try [@ValidateIf](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#conditional-validation) conditional validation

If ValidateIf return `true` then the other validation will run

examle : in this case if `o.otherProperty === 'value'` then the `@IsNotEmpty` will run otherwise it will not run

```
export class Post {
  otherProperty: string;

  @ValidateIf(o => o.otherProperty === 'value')
  @IsNotEmpty()
  example: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`Custom validation classes`](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#custom-validation-classes),
Because [nestjs uses it](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#class-validator) you can make it too.